# Blank wp-login.php page after entering credentials

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-theming

Today I went to login into my wordpress admin but I am getting a blank page after entering in my login details (`wp-login.php` is a blank white page).

So far I have:

1. Disabled all plugins through phpmyadmin (nothing changes)
2. Disabled the active theme (Colormag) and set the default theme to twentysixteen (doesnt fix anything)
3. I enabled debugging in the `wp-config.php` (doesn't give me an error message)
4. the `error_log` file isnt giving me anything either
5. Also cleared my cache, etc. Still Nothing.

I am pretty much at my whits end to say the least. I have been using wordpress themes for nearly 6 years and never had anything like this happen.

So my main question is (besides some person on hear knowing what exactly is wrong) **how can I get a debug/trace log showing me where the issue is happening?** The main site itself is functioning perfectly, it just kinks up at the login page.

Oh, the WP version is 4.4.2

Comment: please show some code so we can see whats going on.

Comment: `How to enable php error reporting` = [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: What files do you need to see?

Comment: I have already enabled all that for debugging

Comment: Is this happening in browsers other than the one this originally occurred in? It could be as simple as a caching/temporary files issue. It is worth double-checking before you go on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0):

You say your browser shows a blank page?

Have you tried to open web developer tools (ctrl+shift+i in chrome) to debug what is happening? You would be able to see if there are javascript errors on the page and under "Network" you can check what the response of the actual wp-config.php request is. If the response is empty the issue is with your webserver or php and you should check the php log files. In the case of apache these are located somewhere in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (by default).

Clearing your browser cache, like Cale mentioned, is also a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing white screen of death. http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors

Usually it's the issue with the theme when in `functions.php` there are some newlines preceding or following the code. Since it's not the issue of the theme (you changed it), it might be an issue caused by the plugin. Try to disable plugins one by one until the problem is fixed to discover which plugin might be causing the issue.

This might be helpful also:
https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/wordpress-white-screen-of-death/

Comment: I disabled all plugins, same thing. Thanks for the link though, I'll give it a look.